# Need help getting the correct layout

Tags: html, css

I have some problems laying out my elements. I tried to achieve the following layout in my web application:

[image: The layout should look like this]

I tried to use **div**´s and style them but it looks like this when I run it

[image: what the layout looks like]

I wanted to create a grid with three container in each row. Also for responsiveness I used **flexbox**.

Any suggestions how the layout could improve? I think I messed it up a little.

```css
.contacts-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

h1.subheading {
  color: red;
}

.contact {
  flex: 0 0 32%;
  /* don't grow, don't shrink, width */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.contact a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.contactInfo {
  padding: 1.4em;
  float: left;
}

.contactInfo h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.contactInfo p {
  font-size: 95%;
}

.contactInfo .contactName {
  float: right;
}

.contactDetails {
  float: left;
}

.contactDetails img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#contact .contact-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* Using flexbox with media queries to make the layout responsive*/

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .contacts-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: -1em;
  }
  .contact-info {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 0.5em);
    margin-bottom: 1em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 60em) {
  .contacts-container {
    margin-top: inherit;
  }
  .contact-info {
    flex: 0 1 calc(33% - 1em);
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
  <h1 class="subheading">Deine Kontakte</h1>
  <div class="contacts-container">
    <div v-for="contact in contacts" class="contact" :key="contact.name">
      <div class="contactInfo">
        <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" />
        <div class="contactName">
          <p>Prename Surname</p>
          <p>City</p>
          <p>Country</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contactDetails">
        <div>
          <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" style="" /> test@test.com
        </div>

        <div>
          <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" /> test@test.com
        </div>

        <div>
          <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" /> test@test.com
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="contact-buttons">
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.contacts {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contact {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact .contactInfo {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact .contactInfo img {}

.contact .contactInfo .contactName {
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact .contactDetails {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contact .contactDetails div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

.contact .contactDetails div p {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact .contact-buttons {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
  <h1 class="subheading">Deine Kontakte</h1>
  <div class="contacts-container">
    <div v-for="contact in contacts" class="contact" :key="contact.name">
      <div class="contactInfo">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        <div class="contactName">
          <p>Prename Surname</p>
          <p>City</p>
          <p>Country</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contactDetails">
        <div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
          <p>test@test.com</p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
          <p>test@test.com</p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
          <p>test@test.com</p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="contact-buttons">
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.contact {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.contactInfo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.contactDetails {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.contactDetailsRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.contactName,
.contactDetailsRowName {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.contact-buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.contact-buttons > button {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="contactInfo">
    <div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="contactName">
      <h5>Prename Surname</h5>
      <p>City</p>
      <p>Country</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contactDetails">
    <div class="contactDetailsRow">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/>
      </div>
      <div class="contactDetailsRowName">
        test@test.com
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contactDetailsRow">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/>
      </div>
      <div class="contactDetailsRowName">
        test@test.com
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contactDetailsRow">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/>
      </div>
      <div class="contactDetailsRowName">
        test@test.com
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-buttons">
    <button>Add 1</button>
    <button>Add 1</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Been a while but something like this?

```css
:root {
  --baseMargin: 1.4em;
  --buttonBorderRadius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  --paddingBaseFill: calc(var(--baseMargin) * 2);
}

.contactInfo img {
  min-width: 10em;
}

.contacts-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

h1.subheading {
  color: red;
}

.contact {
  flex: 0 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* don't grow, don't shrink, width */
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 var(--baseMargin);
}

.contact a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.contactInfo {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: var(--paddingBaseFill) 0;
}

.contactInfo h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.contactInfo p {
  font-size: 95%;
}

.contactInfo .contactName {
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-left: var(--baseMargin);
  text-align: center;
  
}

.contactDetails {
  flex: 1 1;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
}
.contactDetails div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.contactDetails img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.contact-buttons {
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: var(--baseMargin) 0;
}
.contact-buttons button {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: #018bff;
  border-radius: var(--buttonBorderRadius);
  padding: 0.25em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts">
  <h1 class="subheading">Deine Kontakte</h1>
  <div class="contacts-container">
    <div v-for="contact in contacts" class="contact" :key="contact.name">
      <div class="contactInfo wrapper">
        <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" />
        <div class="contactName">
          <p>Prename Surname</p>
          <p>City</p>
          <p>Country</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="contactDetails wrapper">
        <div>
          <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" style="" /> test@test.com
        </div>

        <div>
          <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" /> test@test.com
        </div>

        <div>
          <img :src="getImage(contactImg)" /> test@test.com
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="contact-buttons wrapper">
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
        <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```